# Open specific part of file in Media player

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to play a specific part of a binary file in Media player.
for example:
i know from position 200 to 60000 in a binary file, i have a mp3 data.
how can i play this part without make a file from this.

Answer (score 0):

For playing an mp3 file you can use [WMPLib](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564585(v=vs.85).aspx).
For example:

```
var wmPlayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
wmPlayer.URL = "yourPath";
wmPlayer.Controls.Play();
```

If you want to play specific place of a file as you say it's better to read that amount of file with FileStream class and for skipping some bytes use `Seek` method. for reading specific amount of data use `Read(Byte[], Int32, Int32)` method.
For example:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream("yourPath", FileMode.Open))
{
    var data = new byte[60000 - 200];
    fs.Seek(200, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    fs.Read(data, 0, 60000 - 200);
}
```

And then use [Alvas.Audio](http://alvas.net/alvas.audio.aspx) to play from memory Stream and byte array:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(data))
{
     Mp3Reader mr = new Mp3Reader(ms);
     PlayerEx plex = new PlayerEx();
     plex.OpenPlayer(mr.ReadFormat());
     plex.AddData(mr.ReadData());
     plex.StartPlay();            
}
```

Comment: Yeah, How i can send that part to Media Player?

Comment: Can i play video with this way?

Comment: With WMPLib, you can play video too. check this document: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562692(v=vs.85).aspx